# First isomorphism theorem application

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let G be a group with, $N\subset G$ a normal subgroup, And assume that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, $H\subset G$. Further $HN=G$ and $H\cap N = \{e\}$ . Prove that $H$ generates the cosets of $N$ in $G$. And that $G/N \approxeq H$.

The first part of this problem is a bit vague to me. But my idea was that I had to prove that for a given $g\in G$, there is an $h\in H$ so that $\{gN\}=\{hN\}$.

And I thought to use the first isomorphism theorem for the second part which would give me $G/N=HN/N≅H/H∩N≅H$. However I do not know how to produce this $HN/N≅H/H\cap N$.

Comment: 1. Yes, your interpretation is correct. 2. One of the isomorphism theorems states exactly $HN/N\cong H/H\cap N$ for general subgroup $H$ and normal subgroup $N$.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $HN=G$ tells you that, if $g\in G$, then $g=xy$ for some $x\in H$ and $y\in N$. Then
$$
gN=xyN=xN
$$
because $yN=N$.

What precisely is the first isomorphism theorem is a bit vague: the terminology is imprecise and varies from author to author. In any case a basic theorem in group theory is that, under the assumption that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then
$$
HN/N \cong H/(H\cap N)
$$
The isomorphism can be obtained by considering the homomorphism
$$
f\colon H\to HN/N,\qquad f(x)=xN
$$
There are a couple of things to note here: first $HN$ is a subgroup of $G$ (prove it), second $N$ is normal in $HN$ (obvious).

Its kernel is
$$
\ker f=\{x\in H:f(x)=N\}
$$
since $N$ is the neutral element in $HN/N$. But $xN=N$ is the same as $x\in N$, so $\ker f=H\cap N$ and so the fundamental isomorphism theorem says that
$$
H/\ker f\cong HN/N
$$
which is our thesis.

Finally, $H\cap N=\{e\}$, by hypothesis, so $H/(H\cap N)=H/\{e\}\cong H$.